# Problem in finding examples of linear 0perators $T$ and $U$ such that $TU=-UT$ holds.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Give examples of two invertible linear operators $T$ and $U$ such that $TU=-UT$ holds.

Please help me in finding this example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To begin, what does $TU=-UT$ tell you about the eigenvalues of $T$ and $U$?

Comment: **Hint:** For invertible $U$, this becomes $$UTU^{-1}=-T$$

Comment: But can you provide me an example?

Comment: @Arnab of course. However, we'd prefer that you put some amount of effort into answering the question yourself first.

Comment: For Googling purposes, such operators are said to _anticommute_.

Answer (score 0):

For example, take
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \qquad \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: If one is willing to work with complex Hermitean matrices, then one can include $\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}$ which anticommutes with the above as well. (Together, these are known in physics as the three Pauli matrices and show up frequently in quantum mechanics.)

Comment: I have found one such.Which is $\pmatrix {0&1\\-1&0}$ and $\pmatrix {0&-1\\-1&0}$.Also I found that for such matrix $P$ and $Q$, $Trace(P) = Trace(Q) = 0$.Sorry for the delay to respond.The reason is the time when I  asked it was a time for me to sleep.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out! The point of my comment was to note that $T$ is similar to $-T$, just as $U$ is similar to $-U$.